# Получить информацию о файлах текущей страницы в браузере

Tags: javascript

Можно ли получить инфу(название и т д) файлов на текущей странице? То есть о html файле, css файлах, нескольких js-файлах?
Например, такого набора файлов, который виден в chrome dev tools.

[image: Пример структуры папок загруженной страницы]

Comment: можно распарсить страницу

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев, что можно сделать если это расширение для chrome? И набор страниц не прикреплен ни к какой html странице?